# Why is Safari causing a Rails CSRF exception where Chrome isn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, iframe, safari, csrf

I want to create sessions in my Rails 4 application via an AJAX request in an iframe.

In the iframe I've included a form for a new session with the attribute `remote: true` as usual, and included `<%= token_tag %>` in the form body as well as `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in the head of the layout.

Chrome has no problem posting this form and creating a session. Under identical conditions Safari causes a CSRF exception.

Why does this happen, and what can I do to stop it? As I understand it, this is not a situation where CSRF is essential, as there is no session to hijack, but I'm still wary of turning it off.

Chrome version: 31.0.1650.63

Safari version: 7.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is the famous 'third party cookies' problem. Safari disables them by default.

More: [How do Third-Party "tracking cookies" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897472/how-do-third-party-tracking-cookies-work)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I still do not understand what is the solution.

Comment: @guyaloni, you either have to work without cookies, or bring the user to your website and set a cookie there

Comment: Not really.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31429589/rail-ajax-and-iframe-in-safari :-(