# previous $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

we can get the reference link using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

But, is there any way to find the reference link of that reference?

Suppose, we go to `abc.php` from `xyz.php` so, in `abc.php`, `xyz.php` is the reference link. So, we are now in `abc.php` but, we came to `xyz.php` from another page. I wanna know that reference.

Comment: oh sure you can

Comment: @Fred-ii- so, how can i do it?

Comment: you try something

Comment: You could store the referer in an array in a session, and access that.

Comment: Besides saving this between requests (only works if the user is on your site), there is no way to do this exactly, though you can follow a technique like the one described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805/how-do-you-access-browser-history)

Answer (score 0):

The previous visited sites are not stored on the HTTP Referer you receive in your code. You can store every user activity in your site but you cannot spy what they do before or after passing your site using HTTP Referers (except the referer received).

There are ways to know previous user activity, like [tracking cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897472/how-do-third-party-tracking-cookies-work) (which are implemented by Amazon and other big websites) but those methods require mutual webmasters approvation.

Also, a friendly bit of advice, **avoid invading users privacy**. This won't do any good to your website reputation.

Comment: thanks! :) i'm not invading users privacy. and i got my answer. just used SESSION.