# When is a cookie considered to be a third party cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, security, cookies

Example:

There is a cookie set on website A and another cookie set on website B. I have open website A in my browser and this website sends an AJAX request to website B. In the context of this request, is the cookie for website A or is the cookie for website B considered a third party cookie?

Comment: "Website" is mostly a subjective human term. Cookies are bound to domain names.

Answer (score 1):

If `website B` sets a cookie on your website A, then it'll be considered a third party cookie for `website A`, It's quite simple.

Secondly, cookies are set by servers, so it may not be right to say "Website B has cookies", Probably you mean to say that Websites B sets some cookies, and Website A sets some cookies on client.

> So, if website A contains an ad that is served by website B, then
> website B can set a cookie in your browser. For example, maybe website
> A uses <iframe src="http://websiteB.com/ad.html> to serve the
> ad from website B. Then when your browser goes to fetch
> http://websiteB.com/ad.html, the response will come back with a
> Set-Cookie header that sets a cookie with some unique random string.
> If website C also includes an ad from website B, then that unique
> cookie will be sent when the ad on website C is fetched from website
> B.

Here's this question with very detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897472/how-do-third-party-tracking-cookies-work)