# why is Firefox not respecting the SameSite=None attribute even when the secure flag is set?

Tags: firefox, cookies, browser, same-origin-policy, samesite

I'm experiencing an issue on Firefox when trying to include a cookie on third-party domains. here's the scenario:

I have a cookie set on `example.com` with the attributes SameSite=None and secure. the domain set on the cookie is `.example.com`. when i perform a fetch request on `example.com` or `ANY.example.com` the cookie is included. however, when i'm on `third-part.com` and make a fetch request to `example.com` the cookie isn't included. it behaves as if the SameSite attribute were set to Lax. other browsers are working fine, and I've tested it on several Chromium-based browsers.

Interestingly, it appears that in macOS, all browsers behave the same way as Firefox. The security configuration was the default in all of my tests.

I've been trying to understand this strange behavior for a few days now, but i can't find any information about it in the documentation. if anyone has knowledge of what might be happening and could contribute, i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Third-Party "tracking cookies" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897472/how-do-third-party-tracking-cookies-work)